# Cannot install last version of OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, ffmpeg, make, opencv, cmake

I try to install opencv using the instructions from [here](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/) but I get every time the error

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:191: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4022: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:133: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When I run `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..` it says everything is fine and the libraries are installed. What might happen and how can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this StackOverflow question: [Installing OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.10](//stackoverflow.com/q/26592577/2461638)

You can `cmake` with `-D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF` or manually compile FFmpeg with version 9, as OpenCV needs.